# HTML/CSS Center captions for list items

Tags: html, css

I want to replicate this design

[image]

So far i have managed to create only one part of it. I cannot figure out how to align the captions below the information so that the are always centered with the text above. For example when the information is smaller or larger the alignment is off. 
Any help would be appreciated.

```css
.list-inline {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.list-inline > li {
    display: inline;
}

/*.list-pipe > li:not(:last-child)::after {
    content: '|';
    margin: 0 .25em;
}*/


.list-pipe > li {
    border-right: 1px solid #00000065;
    margin: 0 .25em;
    padding: 1em 1em 2em 1em;
    font-size: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 0.79px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #11A8A1;

}

.list-inline > li:last-child {
   border-right: none;
}

.list-caption {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 54px;
}

.list-caption > li {
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 30px;
    font-size: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 0.79px;
    text-align: center;
}

.list-caption > li:first-child {
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 51px;
    font-size: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 0.79px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-inline list-pipe" >
  <li>
    Germany
  </li>
  <li>
    1914-18
  </li>
  <li>
    German
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="list-caption" >
  <li>
    Place
  </li>
  <li>
    Year
  </li>
  <li>
    Language
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The first thing you should be thinking is making the lists equal width. Then you will not need all the extra margins & padding you have in place.

Comment: Terrible way to express this information in HTML - you are deliberately ripping apart pieces of information that do actually belong together. Even using a table would make much more sense semantically, than what you have concocted here with those separate lists.

Comment: @04FS as far as i know it not bad to try even if your first try is "Terrible". I don't think terrible is a word to use when someone is at least trying to learn.

Comment: A car crash that leaves half a dozen people dead is still a terrible thing, even if the driver causing it was still “learning” :-) Don’t take this personal, but please acknowledge that this is not a personal training ground, but that other people with similar problems might find your question in their future research … And in _that_ regard I think it needs pointing out how bad this approach actually is. Choosing the HTML code based on what they want things to _look like_ in the end is a mistake too many beginners make anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have updated your `html` and `css` code

please let me know if that works for you

```css
ul.list-inline.list-pipe {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
ul.list-inline.list-pipe li {
    width: 33%;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 0.79px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #11A8A1;
    border-left: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
}
ul.list-inline.list-pipe li:first-child {
    border-left: none;
}
ul.list-inline.list-pipe li span {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-inline list-pipe" >
  <li>
    Germany
    <span>Place</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    1914-18
    <span>Year</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    German
    <span>Language</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this easily by the following fiddle. No need to use those much list tags in your code. Always try writing DRY codes. This is a sample code and you can make necessary modifications as per your requirements

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u8h2a15q/1/)

```
.lists {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   list-style:none;
   display:flex
 }
.lists li {
   display:flex;
   flex-direction:column;
   border-right: 1px solid #000000;
   padding: 4px 10px;
   justify-content:center;
   text-align:center;
   font-size:18px
}
.lists li:last-child {
   border:none
 }
.lists li > span:first-child {
   color: #11A8A1;
 }
```

Comment: That works too! You are right. My code was messy and that was definitely on factor that was making it hard for me to understand my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

```
Use below css.

.list-inline {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
    }
    list-pipe > li {
        text-align: center;
        color: #11A8A1;

    }
    .list-inline > li {
        float: left;
        width: 150px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .list-caption {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
        clear: left;
    }
    .list-caption > li {
        text-align: center;
        float: left;
        width: 150px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use flexbox.

```css
.big {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: cetner;
  justify-content: center;
}

.list-inline {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.list-inline > li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.list-inline > li > .title {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #11A8A1;
}

.list-pipe > li {
  border-right: 1px solid #00000065;
  padding: 1em 1em 1em 1em;
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 0.79px;
  text-align: center;
}

.list-inline > li:last-child {
 border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="big">
<ul class="list-inline list-pipe" >
  <li>
    <div class="title">Germany</div>
    <div>Place</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="title">1914-18</div>
    <div>Year</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="title">German</div>
    <div>Language</div>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```